# In Eclipse, is there a short cut key to open a editor in a New Window?

Tags: eclipse

I am editing a .java file in eclipse, is there a short cut key to launch/open the current .java file I am editing into a new window to make use of my multiple displays?

I am using Eclipse 3.x

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut key in Eclipse to reopen a file in a new window, but I'm unclear on how that would work anyway. Maybe I'm missing something, but how would Eclipse know which display to use, where to position the new window on the display, and what dimensions to use for the new window? And even if it did know how to do all that, it's not improbable that you would still want to adjust the size and positioning of the new window.

Besides, there already is a better alternative to a shortcut key: just position the mouse cursor over the tab of the open file, drag it to wherever you want on any of your displays, and optionally resize that new window as desired. The change will persist over restarts of Eclipse.

(I verified this on the latest release of Eclipse, Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2, but I don't know when that drag and drop functionality was first implemented.)

Comment: The tab drag option is not in 3.x, I was hoping this was supported in some way.

Comment: @xpagesbeast OK - I'll see if there is any other approach. What is the exact version of Eclipse you are using?...